# Open Jupyter in VSCode: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'makeSettings')

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

System: MacOSX 10.15,
VSCode Version: 1.67.2,
Python Kernel Version: 3.8.13 (Conda base).

I created a new Jupyter notebook in my VSCode using command shortcut and selected the right python kernel showed above. The empty notebook page is well loaded and no error message occurred.

But when I typed and ran any code in the cell, this error message showed up below the cell.

[image]

Then I clicked the "log" link and the error log showed up and it was like this:

[image]

And hence I couldn't run any code in the notebook cell. Then I changed to another Python Kernel (3.9.12) of the same notebook, it showed the same error message:

[image]

Please give me a solution to overcome this bug.

*Update:* I tried to reinstall pyzmq to an older version in the canda base environment and it didn't change anything. Then I typed command `jupyter --version` and everything is well installed.

*Update:* I have searched on Github Issues of VSCode. There are two similar issues that are all caused by some extensions, one is called "Gitduck"(now renamed "duckly"), the other is "nur.Script". The link to these issues are here:

[Cannot read property 'makeSettings' of undefined #834](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/834)

[Cannot read property 'makeSettings' of undefined #128458](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128458)

But unfortunately, I never have installed any of these extensions in my VSCode. So it may be caused by a similar extension but I still don't know the name.

Finally, I use the command `code --list-extensions` to list all my installed extensions here, maybe helpful for filtering which extension is the bad guy:

[image]

*Final Update:* Today (05/31) I opened VSCode and tentatively created an empty Jupyter notebook, and this problem has gone away. I have done nothing, maybe VSCode's auto-update has solved this problem. Case closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try reinstalling the `pyzmq` module.

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq==19.0.2
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but in what environment that I should do this reinstalling? I tested both conda base (3.8.13) and (3.9.12) and they were all have the problem. Or I need to reinstall it for every environment that I currently keep using?

Comment: Yes, reinstall in your current working environment.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `jupyter --version`
Command to check if there are not installed libraries in jupyter.If it is `not installed`, use the `pip install ...` command to install.

Comment: I tried reinstalling pyzmq in the conda base environment (3.8.13), but the problem still exists. Then I typed `jupyter --version` in the terminal, and it showed like this: `Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.3.0
ipykernel        : 6.9.1
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.2.2
jupyter_core     : 4.10.0
jupyter_server   : 1.13.5
jupyterlab       : 3.3.2
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.4.4
nbformat         : 5.3.0
notebook         : 6.4.11
qtconsole        : 5.3.0
traitlets        : 5.1.1`

Comment: Different versions of anaconda correspond to different python environments.
Maybe you can try to download the corresponding version from [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=3.10.0)